# Projeto MVC DDD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ddd

Eu estou criando uma aplicação, utilizando o padrão DDD, então, na minha camada de Apresentação, eu crio as viewModel, e na controller eu uso o `Mapper.Map<Entidade, EntidadeViewModel>` . eu gostaria de saber o seguinte. no meu dominio, eu uso alguns Enuns, eu preciso criar as ViewModel desses Enuns? na verdade, eu ja criei, mas não deu muito certo.
Segue o Cód Enum:

```
public enum EstadoViewModel
    {
        [Description("Rondônia")]
        RO = 11,
        [Description("Acre")]
        AC = 12,
        [Description("Amazonas")]
        AM = 13,
        [Description("Roraima")]
        RR = 14,
        [Description("Pará")]
        PA = 15,
        [Description("Amapá")]
        AP = 16,
        [Description("Tocantins")]
        TO = 17,
        [Description("Maranhão")]
        MA = 21,
        [Description("Piauí")]
        PI = 22,
        [Description("Ceará")]
        CE = 23,
        [Description("Rio Grande do Norte")]
        RN = 24,
        [Description("Paraíba")]
        PB = 25,
        [Description("Pernambuco")]
        PE = 26,
        [Description("Alagoas")]
        AL = 27,
        [Description("Sergipe")]
        SE = 28,
        [Description("Bahia")]
        BA = 29,
        [Description("Minas Gerais")]
        MG = 31,
        [Description("Espírito Santo")]
        ES = 32,
        [Description("Rio de Janeiro")]
        RJ = 33,
        [Description("São Paulo")]
        SP = 35,
        [Description("Paraná")]
        PR = 41,
        [Description("Santa Catarina")]
        SC = 42,
        [Description("Rio Grande do Sul")]
        RS = 43,
        [Description("Mato Grosso do Sul")]
        MS = 50,
        [Description("Mato Grosso")]
        MT = 51,
        [Description("Goiás")]
        GO = 52,
        [Description("Distrito Federal")]
        DF = 53

    }
```

Dessa maneira ta salvando no banco na minha tabela que recebe o enum, como 0.
Então, eu preciso criar os enumViewModel? ou basta usar os enum da camada de dominio mesmo? adicionando assim, uma referencia na minha camada de Apresentação, para a camada de dominio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tópico aberto a bastante tempo hein! Já conseguiu resolver?
Vamos lá, o bom seria você isolar os Enumeradores em outro projeto da solução, fixando na camada de aplicação, pois tu pode vir a utilizar em outros projetos da solução, Digamos que assim tu estará utilizando uma nova tipificação de atributo e referencia nos projetos ao qual farão uso do mesmo.

No domínio o campo da entidade que tu irá submeter tu poderá declarar como o Enum criado:

```
EstadoViewModel estado{ get; set;}
```

para o banco será reconhecido como Int.

Mas caso não queira criar nesse modelo você pode lidar com o teu Enum na camada de Apresentação e no domínio colocar o campo como Int.

No teu mapeamento o teu Enum você deve fazer a conversão para Int. Assim odado irá para o banco corretamente.

Comment: Já resolvi.. eu coloquei os enums separados, e uso eles em qualquer parte do proejto.. ou seja o meu `ClienteDominio.Enum` tem o mesmo enum que o `ClienteViewModel.Enum`. Até o momento nao tive problema ao usar assim. Obrigado!!

Comment: Show de Bola. Agora que vi o teu post.