# Em qual camada devo criar constantes em minha aplicação com conceito DDD?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ddd

Estou usando o conceito DDD (Camadas: Presentation, Application, Domain, Data e CrossCutting) em minha aplicação ASP.NET Core MVC e me surgiu uma dúvida sobre qual o melhor local para criar minhas constantes.

No meu *domain* criei uma classe `ContatoTipo` (`Id`, `Descricao`) que conterá os dados (TELEFONE FIXO, TELEFONE RESIDENCIAL, TELEFONE CELULAR, etc). Precisarei criar constantes para tais dados, para serem usados nas demais camadas para poder fazer validações, etc. Elas devem ser criadas na camada Domain? Devem ser criadas na mesma classe *model* `ContatoTipo`? Tenho medo de expor demais o meu *domain*.

Comment: Que tipos de contantes?

Comment: Tipo Int para representar o Id e string para a Descricao. Tenho várias classes semelhantes que precisarei fazer o mesmo... ;)

Comment: Vou responder, mas a não ser que esteja falando algo errado não precisa de constante.

Comment: Mostra um exemplo de uma classe que implementa essa relação com a Classe ContatoTipo...

Comment: Por exemplo, imagine que na minha view eu precisasse fazer um if para validar se o contato == telefone fixo (Id = 1). Imagine que algum dia, eu precise mudar o valor do Id do telefone fixo de 1 para 50... Fica tenso eu sair procurando no projeto inteiro, onde ficam os validações e alterar tudo para 50....Não me parece produtivo....

Comment: @Maniero, eu acredito que ele deve estar se confundindo com Enums, mas sem ver a modelagem fica difícil, uma vez que o Telefone poderia ser um VO de Telefone.

Comment: Na vdd, criei uma tabela no banco de dados (ContatoTipo) e uma classe (ContatoTipo) que serão de uso exclusivo do sistema... o Usuário não poderá alterar. Neste caso, não estou criando um enumerador (Seria mais fácil, mas precisei salvar mais informações, por isso enum não seriviria)..

Comment: Mas a validação do dominio fica necessariamente no dominio (ou em alguma outra camada que esteja relacionada diretamente no dominio). Não vejo sentido em ter que alterar em N lugares se X que era 1 passar pra 50, até pq se era 1 e passou pra 50, como ficam os registros anteriores? vai sair dando update em tudo? Não faz mais sentido ainda. Acredito que exista aí um problema de abstração do problema. Eu criaria as Enums no Dominio e não dependeria de um tipo Int para determinar o tipo de telefone, uma vez que sendo 1 ou 50, o telefone é Fixo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Projeto MVC DDD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394202/projeto-mvc-ddd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro faça algumas considerações: [Constante é realmente útil?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203151/101) e [Qual é a diferença entre const e readonly?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101) (o mais importante é a filosofia de uso de cada).

Assim como variáveis as constantes devem ser declaradas o mais próximo de onde elas são usadas ou pelo menos em lugar que faça sentido.

Não sou especialista em DDD mas nunca vi nada nesta disciplina falando sobre isso. Imagino que entendem que é uma decisão sua e que você terá bom senso em colocar no local adequado, como os demais artefatos. DDD e outras técnicas que as pessoas adotam achando que elas melhorarão o código não ajudam do jeito que elas imaginam, o que faz o código ficar bom é conhecimento aprofundado, comprometimento com a qualidade e bom senso. Meio que não se ensina essas coisas, a pessoa vai se formando assim.

## Colocar no domínio ou outro lugar

Se a constante é importante para o domínio então é lá que deve colocar, se ela é mais geral deve colocar em uma camada que comunique com as outras, se é na apresentação que é usado então é lá que deve por. Se tiver dificuldade em saber onde colocar então o problema não é que não sabe onde colocar a constante e sim de colocar qualquer coisa, e provavelmente já está colocando em lugares errados e não importa muito mais, afinal se tudo está errado já deveria abandonar isso e fazer de uma forma que consegue entender e fazer correto.

Eu não vejo muita diferença para a constante em relação ao resto da estrutura de dados. E eu não sei se deveria criar uma constante para o problema, a questão precisa ser muito bem definida para saber. Se não tiver que ter essa constante então todos os lugares estão errados. O comentário diz que nem precisa de constante.

Se é um valor padrão que usa para alguma coisa então pode até ser uma constante (mas eu acho que é só [um dado imutável e não uma constante de fato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151721/101), se usar esse mecanismo poderá até ter problemas em certa forma de compilar), e deve ser ali, valor padrão faz parte do domínio, ele não faz parte do objeto, mas um valor estático ainda faz parte do domínio.

Pode ser que alguém diga alguma coisa que o DDD não deveria ter valores estáticos, se isso for verdade pode ser bom ou ruim. Pode ser bom porque ele pode exigir um mecanismo diferente para dar mais flexibilidade, mas manter em outra classe pra mim dificulta o entendimento e até legibilidade do código, você tem que lembrar da existência dessa outra classe.

Por outro lado novos comentários acima falam em mais alguma coisa que pode ser que isto seja outra coisa e deva ser só outro domínio e nem constante. Pode ser um domínio auxiliar para usar no domínio principal. Não tem informação clara o suficiente pra cravar (e nem é fácil colocar tudo o que precisa em uma pergunta). Isto seria interessante porque daria flexibilidade. De uma certa forma usaria um dos mecanismos do dicionário de dados (veja abaixo) :)

Não ficou claro se deveria ser uma constante, mas DDD costuma usar atributos com literais (que são constantes sem nome) então pode ser certo, por tudo isto torna o código menos flexível e mais difícil de dar manutenção, o que eu considero uma falha do DDD e outras técnicas que pregam o mesmo.

Eu prefiro [dicionário de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347190/101) para dar flexibilidade e facilitar a manutenção muito mais que DDD (curiosamente ele pode ser dinâmico o que daria a mesma sigla :) ).

## Conclusão

Eu sou um crítico que uma técnica que pegou moda ficou famosas mas é cheia de falhas. As pessoas usam pela fama e desconhecimento de outras técnicas e não pela qualidade dela.

Mas se a metodologia toda já for inadequada não dá para arrumar totalmente sem abandoná-la.

Note que o texto diz praticamente que precisa colocar no domínio para usar nas outras camadas. Pra mim isto está respondido, não está escrito claramente o domínio, mas se o texto foi escrito corretamente dá para inferir isto.

Comment: Obrigado por melhorar meu raciocínio @Maniero. Acredito que, pelo menos no meu caso, seja apropriada a criação na camada de Domínio. Inclusive, lá já há outras constantes separadas em uma pasta... Vou tentar seguir esse mesmo raciocínio. Obrigado, mais uma vez! :)